# Unicode normalizations in HTML : Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, utf-8, webfonts, unicode-normalization

It seems that different Web browsers cope differently with the various normalizations of Unicode encoding, especially in the presence of nonstandard fonts.

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
ì (2 chars) or ì (1 char)
</body>
</html>
```

works well both with Firefox and Chrome :

ì (2 chars) or ì (1 char)

but when I add a .css style sheet loading some Internet Font (Google Vollkorn), Chrome renders it correctly, but not Firefox.

Could somebody explain what happens ?

Comment: Does the font contain all the necessary glyphs? It sounds like Chrome and Firefox both need to use another font for the `, and Chrome happens to pick one that looks better.

Comment: It's also possible that Chrome performs NFC normalization but Firefox does not.

Comment: To me it seems a font issue and not a normalization (which probably they will not perform: it will create more problem on javascript). Could you try to use the same font on both browsers?  In theory the results should be also dependent on locale.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I used the same file, same css on both browsers, and tried with different Google fonts. The problems does not happen with generic fonts as required in 'font-family: Georgia, serif', but happens (on Firefox) with loaded Google fonts.